# Newtonsoft.Net Do Not Include Fields

Tags: c#, json.net

New to Json, and I was reading a comparison on Newtonsoft.Net vs System.Text.Json, and I am looking to use Newton, but the comparison I read had that Microsoft version has this option an "IncludeFields" option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields?view=net-6.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_IncludeFields

If I am understanding this correctly, Microsoft's won't de/serialize fields - just properties, but Netwonsoft does by default. I tried looking through Newtonsoft's documentation for a similar setting / property.

Mainly because I don't fields to be de/serialized. I only want public properties de/serialized.

Is there a setting I'm just not seeing to prevent fields by default?

Comment: Checkout this Newtonsoft attribute, [JsonIgnore](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm)

Comment: The name of the type is `Newtonsoft.Json` and public properties and fields participate is serialization. You can control what gets included in serialization via attributes and/or custom types and callbacks, as explained in [the documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm), which is extensive and comes with [a ton of examples](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm)....

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. Public properties is all I want to work with. I have had other serializers (not Json) that would serialize fields (not properties) as well and I want to make sure it doesn't do that. I might just be getting my terminology confused, by 'fields' I mean non-property variables at the class level.

Comment: PS. If you look at the MS link I did, MS has a IncludeFields property that is false by default, but turning it to 'true' supposedly makes it handle fields the same way NewtonSoft.Json does. This to me indicates that NewtonSoft does something with fields while System.Text.Json by default only does properties. That's where my current confusion lies.

Comment: In C# a field is indeed a variable at the class level. There is usually a distinction made between those explicitly marked `public` (and therefore exposed to consumers of the objects made from the class) and those not explicitly marked (and therefore default to `private`). And Microsoft chose to only serialize public properties, not public fields, whereas Newtonsoft chose to serialize public properties *and* fields. You have to go out of your way to not include public fields. Microsoft's design docs have been pushing people toward using properties rather than fields for years though...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah I never use public fields - although I do on occasion catch my fellow developers doing it. My main concern was less than public fields - meaning while I enforce always using public properties (never public fields) I have had other serializers reach in and grab non-public fields for serialization / deserialization and that's what I was looking to actively prevent.

Comment: PS, you want to make your last comment the answer I'll mark it as such.